# Convert types from strings to ints in newline delimited JSON file, handling null

Tags: json, jq

We have the following newline-delimited JSON:

```
{"leagueId": "1", "name": "the ballers"}
{"team": "2", "leagueId": "1", "name": "the hoopers"}
{"team": "3", "leagueId": "1", "name": "the gamerrs"}
{"team": "4", "leagueId": "1", "name": "the drivers"}
{"team": "5", "leagueId": "1", "name": "the jumpers"}
{"team": "6", "leagueId": "1", "name": "the riserss"}
```

**team, leagueId** should both be ints, and we'd like to modify this NDJSON converting these strings into ints. The output we're going for is:

```
{"leagueId": 1, "name": "the ballers"}
{"team": 2, "leagueId": 1, "name": "the hoopers"}
{"team": 3, "leagueId": 1, "name": "the gamerrs"}
{"team": 4, "leagueId": 1, "name": "the drivers"}
{"team": 5, "leagueId": 1, "name": "the jumpers"}
{"team": 6, "leagueId": 1, "name": "the riserss"}
```

Assuming we know / have a list/array of the columns that need to be converted from strings into ints [team, leagueId], how can we do this conversion? Is this possible with (a) a bash command using a tool like `jq`, or (b) is there some python solution? Our full NDJSON is ~10GB in size, and performance is important as this is a step in our daily data-ingestion pipeline.

**Edit:** `jq -c '{leagueId: .leagueId | tonumber, team: .team | tonumber, name: .name}' tmp/testNDJSON.json > tmp/new_output.json` it seems like this *this would* work if not for the missing `team` value in the first JSON... any help is appreciated!

Comment: Why do you use a bunch of JSON objects instead of a single JSON object with arrays? Doesn't really make sense  IMHO.

Comment: We use newline-delimited JSON, it is the format outputted to us when we export from our database.

Comment: Can't those field types simply be changed from string to integer directly in your database client? Shouldn't be a problem.

Comment: our database is mongodb, and yes we actually have an okay working solution with pymongo's `collection.update_many()` that updates types directly in mongo. however (a) it is fairly slow and we're searching for a faster solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```bsh
jq  -c '.leagueId |= tonumber | (.team // empty) |= tonumber' file
```

This converts the `leagueId` in each object to a number, and then the `team` value, if it exits and is non-null.

Generalized to take an array of keys to turn into numbers, if they exist:

```bsh
jq -c --argjson keys '["team", "leagueId"]' \
    '($keys[] as $key | .[$key] // empty) |= tonumber' file
```

Using [`jo`](https://jpmens.net/2016/03/05/a-shell-command-to-create-json-jo/) to create that list:

```bsh
jq -c --argjson keys "$(jo -a team leagueId)"  \
    '($keys[] as $key | .[$key] // empty) |= tonumber' file
```

What happens here is that the statement `.[$key] // empty` is used for a set of `$key` strings, generating values from the objects where `$key` is an existing key with non-null value.  These values are then converted to numbers.  The `$key` strings are taken from the array passed in on the command line.

Comment: In our full data, we know which keys need to be converted, but we don't know which keys have / don't have missing values. We are looking for a solution that assumes any of the keys may have missing values.

Comment: this solution still provides us enough that i'll accept this answer. thank you so much!

Comment: @Canovice See updated answer.

Comment: I wish I could upvote this more than once

Comment: quick follow up on this - while this command works locally with `jq` version 1.6 on mac, it is not working in our docker container with jq version `jq-1.5-1-a5b5cbe`

`jq: error (at /path_to/file.json:1): Invalid path expression near attempt to iterate through ["team","leagueId"]`. This error message prints once for each line in the file, so we also get `jq: error (at /path_to/file.json:2): Invalid path expression near attempt to iterate through ["team","leagueId"]`

Comment: @Kusalandanda we've tested this on the exact same file locally and on the server

Comment: It does look like the initial command `jq  -c '.leagueId |= tonumber | (.team // empty) |= tonumber' file` with each key listed out works file... I will simply use this instead of the looping approach, and just build the string myself.